# Blockchain.com blocking my account and all transactions pending since one month

Tags: blockchain.info, fraud

I have more than 40BTC blocked in blockchain saving account, they asked me for KYC to send them my official documents and proof of earning of those BTC, I sent all and they ask now for Tax correspondance about those BTC a way to steal my BTC !

An official complaint is being done now with my international lawers.

Ticket#1989121

Anyone have same problem with them ?

Comment: The Blockchain.com wallet is non-custodial, unless you specifically opted to use their trading wallet (to buy/sell BTC using their exchange). If you didn't specifically opt to use the Blockchain.com trading account, I would assume you have been scammed by someone.

Comment: I lost 0.1 BTC like this. Out of the blue they blocked my saving account and asked me to send them my official documents. I sent all and they ask and they say: "Please be advised that your application for identity verification has been temporarily rejected because the document you have used for verification is no longer supported. [...] You will receive another email in the nearest time from Blockchain.com with more details on the information required.". Total scam - the ain't sending anything for month now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the walletID and password, then you could simply download the encrypted backup and sweep your private key to another wallet like electrum and move your funds out without needing to wait for blockchain.com

Comment: Thanks, but they are in the interest account not in wallet, I sent them from the interest account to the wallet, transaction pending since a month now

Comment: They still cannot block your funds. At least they should return them to the account from where it was sent.